# How To Pass Integers To C Code Using Erlang Ports

Tags: erlang

I have referred to the [Erlang Interoperability Tutorial User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) and implemented complex.c complex5.erl and port_driver.c

But the size of data that can be passed was limited to `1 byte`. 
I went through the docs and passed this additional parameter in `complex5.erl`

```
init(SharedLib) ->
    register(code, self()),
    Port = open_port({spawn, SharedLib}, [{packet, 4}]),
    loop(Port).
```

**Change : passed the tuple** `{packet, 4}`

And made the following change in `port_driver.c`:

```
static void example_drv_output(ErlDrvData handle, char *buff, 
                   ErlDrvSizeT bufflen) {
    example_data* d = (example_data*)handle;
    char fn = buff[0],  res;
    char arg[100];
    getAddress(buff, arg);
    if (fn == 1) {
      res = foo(arg);
    } else if (fn == 2) {
      res = bar(arg);
    }
    driver_output(d->port, &res, 4);
}
```

**Change:** `driver_output(d->port, &res, 4);`

I left the code for encode and decode **unchanged**:

```
encode({foo, X}) -> [1, X];
encode({bar, Y}) -> [2, Y].

decode([Int]) -> Int.
```

Context of use :

```
loop(Port) ->
    receive
    {call, Caller, Msg} ->
        Port ! {self(), {command, encode(Msg)}},
        receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            Caller ! {code, decode(Data)}
        end,
        loop(Port);
    stop ->
        Port ! {self(), close},
        receive
        {Port, closed} ->
            exit(normal)
        end;
    {'EXIT', Port, Reason} ->
        io:format("~p ~n", [Reason]),
        exit(port_terminated)
    end.
```

Foo function:

```
int foo(int x) {
  return 500;
}
```

But I now get the error :

```
Error in process <0.47.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{complex,decode,[[252,1,192,135]],[{file,"complex.erl"},{line,62}]},{complex,loop,1,[{file,"complex.erl"},{line,45}]}]}
```

Are there any other changes I need to make or otherwise, how do I send integers and receive integers from the C code?

**EDIT**: I got rid of the error by modifying my decode function to the following:

```
decode(Int) -> 
    Bin=list_to_binary(Int),
    <<N:32 /integer>> = Bin, 
    N.
```

But now, N holds the value **4093707712** when I call foo.

Comment: The error message says that there is no function clause in the function decode/1 from module complex that match with the parameter `[252,1,192,135]`. Nothing in your post shows what is expected by this function and in which context it is called. You should give details about this.

Comment: I have added the code for encode and decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following modifications to port_driver.c solved the problem.

```
static void example_drv_output(ErlDrvData handle, char *buff, 
                       ErlDrvSizeT bufflen)
    {
        example_data* d = (example_data*)handle;
        char fn = buff[0], arg = buff[1];
        int* res =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (fn == 1) {
          *res = htonl(foo(arg));
        } else if (fn == 2) {
          *res = htonl(bar(arg));
        }
        driver_output(d->port, (char*)res, 4);
    }
```

The **htonl()** function converts the unsigned integer hostlong from host byte order to network byte order.

Answer (score 0):

The decode function, as it is written, expect a list of one element exactly: `[Int]` while the message is a list of 4 elements: `[252,1,192,135]`.

That not so bad since it seems you succeed to sent the message `{self(), {command, encode(Msg)}}` to the C Port, that it was understood, and that the returned value was interpreted as `{Port, {data, Data}}` with Port having the right value.

Looking at the code in the link, Data should be an integer while you get a list of 4 integers. I guess the modification you made in the driver and the option `{packet, 4}` are responsible for that.

Comment: Say my function is `foo(int x){ return 500;}`, how do I receive this value in erlang?

Comment: Ok, I assumed that I was receiving data in binary so I changed my decode  function to this: `decode(Int) -> 
 Bin=list_to_binary(Int),
 <<N:32 /integer>> = Bin, 
 N.`

Comment: Also am I allowed to make the above change in the question?

Comment: I now get the value **4093706432**, and I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: The modification you made (remove bracket and use list_to_binary) only solve the clause matching issue, but the root cause is not solved. You received different values instead of 500 ([252,1,192,135],[244,1,5,192],[244,1,0,192]???), you should make sure that res in the c driver is equal to 500, and then try to look into the driver_output code what will be the effect of using the 4 as las parameter (I have not the spec of this code).

Comment: I think the problem comes from storing it in `res` which is of type `char`. But the `driver_output` function requires the return type to be of type char. Isn't 4 as a parameter just specifying that my return value if of size 4 bytes?

Comment: In your example res is a char, the 3rd parameter in the output_driver function (according to [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_driver.html#driver_output)) is the size of the data to be sent in byte, so 1 for a char.

Comment: But doesn't res have to be of type char?

Comment: I have to pass 4 as a parameter because otherwise, I'll get the error:`Error in process <0.40.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,<<1 byte>>},[{complex,decode,1,[{file,"complex.erl"},{line,64}]},{complex,loop,1,[{file,"complex.erl"},{line,45}]}]}`